# How to pass JSON value that can be able to use in IONIC HTML page

Tags: json, eclipse, ionic-framework, visual-studio-code

I'm very new to Ionic framework. 
I'm developing an app that can be able to view lyrics of songs.

I have able to pass JSON value from Restfull GET method and retrieve from Ionic Lycris Page.

Restfull respose :

```html
[{"id":{"timestamp":1518581174,"machineIdentifier":3380871,"processIdentifier":2512,"counter":3611533,"time":1518581174000,"date":1518581174000,"timeSecond":1518581174},"songId":1,"lyrics":"You, do you remember me <br> Like I remember you?<br> Do you spend your life<br>Going back in your mind to that time?<br><br> Cause I, I walk the streets alone<br>I hate being on my own<br>And everyone can see that I really fell<br>And I'm going through hell<br>Thinking about you with somebody else<br><br>Somebody wants you<br>Somebody wants you<br>Somebody dreams about you every single night<br>Somebody can't breathe, without you it's lonely<br>Somebody hopes that one day you will see<br>That somebody's me [2x]<br>Yeah<br><br>How, how did we go wrong?<br>It was so good and now it's gone<br>And I pray at night that our paths soon will cross<br>And what we had isn't lost<br>Cause you're always right here in my thoughts<br><br>Somebody wants you<br>Somebody needs you<br>Somebody dreams about you every single night<br>Somebody can't…<br>"}]
```

**Ionic App**
[Ionic Page View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xv9lz.jpg)

The question is I need to display song lyrics with line break except all in one.

I've tried using `<br>`, but is doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

use something like this

```
  newlineString = lyrics.replace( /\u21b5/g ,"\n");
```